# How do you position the x-axis labels along the line y=0 using Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to move the x-axis labels so that they appear along the line x=0. The scales are constantly changing, so I don't want to set the location using pixels, as y=0 may not be in the same location for each plot.

I tried looking up this question on this site and someone recommended using "crossing:0," as shown below, but that doesn't work.

```
xAxis: {
  min: -20,
  max: 20,
  tickInterval: 1,
   gridLineWidth: 1,
    endOnTick: false,
     crossing:0,
    title: {
        text: 'some value', 
    },
```

If someone could help me with this positioning, I would appreciate it.

Here's my JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7eyv/35/

Answer (score 3):

`crossing` is not an out-of-the-box feature of Highcharts.

Based on what I could find, it seems what you want is the "Crossing-Specific-Value" Highcharts plugin, which is located here: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/6/Crossing-Specific-Values

**Update (July 5, 2016):** To address the comments about your fiddle, you need to explicitly add the "Crossing-Specific-Value" plugin after your bring in the Highcharts library (see the third line below):

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/highslide-software/crossing-specific-value/master/crossing-specific-value.js"></script>
```

Now, adding the `crossing` variable to your x-axis will show the labels as in the demo.

I made a few tweaks to your fiddle (see http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/z7eyv/38/) to better suit what you're asking.

1) Using the demo as the default, it seems that the plugin puts your labels above the axis line. I've seen instances where the labels are better ready **below** the line so I did the following:

```
  xAxis: {
    crossing: 0,
    opposite: true,
    min: -20,
    max: 20,
    tickInterval: 1,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    endOnTick: false,
    title: { text: '' },
    labels: { y: 15 }       // pushes the labels down below the crossing line
  },
```

2) I then adjusted the plot line for the y-axis as follows:

```
  yAxis: {
    min: -20,
    max: 20,
    tickInterval: 1,
    endOnTick: false,
    title: { text: 'some value' },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0.1,
      width: 1,
      color: 'black',
      zIndex: 10 }]     // moves the plot line above the axis gridline
  },
```

The `zIndex` value of 10 means the line will show up on top of the normal gridline. Here's how this looks:

[image]

Please let me know if this better answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I saw that write-up, but I don't see how that's any different from what I did in my JsFiddle. They seem to use "crossing" in the same way that I did. Am I missing a difference somewhere in the code?

Comment: As Mike said, at this moment you need to use the extension or your own code like you have, because this is not build-in.

Comment: @user3666954 I've updated my answer. Please let me know if my expanded explanation is more helpful.